# Django NoReverseMatch wrong number of arguments

Tags: python, django

I am getting a NoReverseMatch error after having added a new argument to one of my URLs. Initially, the URL in `urlpatterns` had been

```
url(r'^(?P<myID>[0-9]+)/go/(?P<otherID>[0-9]+)/$', views.go, name='go')
```

and this worked. I changed it to

```
url(r'^(?P<myID>[0-9]+)/go/(?P<listID>[0-9]+)/(?P<otherID>[0-9]+)/$', views.go, name='go')
```

and updated the function `go` in views.py to accept another argument (`def go(request,myID,listID,otherID):#...`). The new argument is not being recognized. When I try to go to `my_app/18/go/14/12/` (for example) from my local server it gives the error

```
Reverse for 'go' with arguments '(18, 12)' and keyword arguments '{}'
not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
['frackr/(?P<myID>[0-9]+)/go/(?P<listID>[0-9]+)/(?P<otherID>[0-9]+)/$']
```

So it seems that it does not recognize the `listID` argument. However, the debugging message says that one of the local variables in the view function is `listID` with the value of `u'14'`. So the problem does not seem to be coming from interpreting the URL.

I have looked through tons of questions already to try to figure this out, but no one seems to have the same problem. And I realize this is probably a beginner's mistake, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You only have 2 arguments `(18, 12)`, but your URL pattern requires three arguments; so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Check your templates, you may have missed updating the links with new params.

Comment: In views.py, I pass three arguments to the function `go` (`myID`, `listID`, and `otherID`). Shouldn't the arguments passed to `go` be the numbers in the URL string, then? Is there something else I have to do to make the numbers in the URL string be passed to the view, other than adding `url(r'^(?P<myID>[0-9]+)/go/(?P<listID>[0-9]+)/(?P<otherID>[0-9]+)/$', views.go, name='go')` to `urlpatterns`

Comment: I don't link to go from go.html, and that should be the only template that's relevant, right?

Comment: `my_app` or `frackr`? Also check everywhere you're calling that url. In the templates like @Rohan said and in the code itself; `get_absolute_url` for example. Basically search for the url name 'go'.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error isn't related to your function arguments. It explicitly states the error is a `reverse` error.

The traceback will tell you exactly where `reverse` was called from, and that function needs to be updated to use 3 arguments, not 2.

It would be a `reverse()` call directly in python, `{% url %}` via template, `get_absolute_url` with the wrong parameters, etc., but the traceback will tell you exactly where.

Comment: It seems like it's tracing back to the line `return render(request, 'go.html', context)` in the `go` function in views.py. The arguments to `go` are `request`, `myID`, `listID`, and `otherID`. Should there be somewhere to tell `render` which arguments to pass on? I thought it gets the arguments directly from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Post a complete stack trace of error so that it can be known which file is the cause for issue.

Check your templates. There is a possibility that django is trying to call the url in templates using only two args. Try calling url in templates using namespaces and names as given below.

```
{% url 'go' arg1 arg2 arg3 %}
```